# Python fast string parsing, manipulation

Tags: python, performance, string, parsing

I am using python to parse the incoming comma separated string. I want to do some calculation afterwards on the data.
The length of the string is: 800 characters with 120 comma separated fields.
There such 1.2 million strings to process.

```
for v in item.values():
         l.extend(get_fields(v.split(',')))  
#process l
```

get_fields uses operator.itemgetter() to extract around 20 fields out of 120.

This entire operation takes about 4-5 minutes excluding the time to bring in the data.
In the later part of the program I insert these lines into sqlite memory table for further use.
But overall 4-5 minutes time for just parsing and getting a list is not good for my project.

I run this processing in around 6-8 threads.

Does switching to C/C++ might help?

Comment: You're calling a function which needs to iterate through 800 characters, and you're doing it over a million times. Even for a computer, that's a lot to process.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: If you're planning on reinventing the wheel, you should look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join also you should look at generators.

Comment: What do you mean, "excluding the time to bring in the data"?

Comment: Basically I ran the code without string processing and then again after with processing to get the timings for string processing part.

Answer (score 3):

Are you loading a dict with your file records?  Probably better to process the data directly:

```
datafile = file("file_with_1point2million_records.dat")
# uncomment next to skip over a header record
# file.next()

l = sum(get_fields(v.split(',')) for v in file, [])
```

This avoids creating any overall data structures, and only accumulated the desired values as returned by get_fields.

Answer (score 2):

Your program might be slowing down trying to allocate enough memory for 1.2M strings. In other words, the speed problem might not be due to the string parsing/manipulation, but rather in the `l.extend`. To test this hypothsis, you could put a print statement in the loop:

```
for v in item.values():
    print('got here')
    l.extend(get_fields(v.split(',')))
```

If the print statements get slower and slower, you can probably conclude `l.extend` is the culprit. In this case, you may see significant speed improvement if you can move the processing of each line into the loop.

PS: You probably should be using the `csv` module to take care of the parsing for you in a more high-level manner, but I don't think that will affect the speed very much.

Comment: The timeit module (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) may be of help in determining how long things take.

Comment: I suggested a quick and dirty method because if you can't *see* a noticeable slow-down, then memory allocation is not the issue.