# String concatenation in Python

Tags: python, compilation, internals, object-identity

Can you describe difference between two ways of string concatenation: simple `__add__` operator and `%s` patterns?
I had some investigation in this question and found `%s` (in form without using parentheses) a little faster.

Also another question was appeared: why result of `'hell%s' % 'o'` refers to another memory region than `'hell%s' % ('o',)`?

There is some code example:

```
l = ['hello', 'hell' + 'o', 'hell%s' % 'o', 'hell%s' % ('o',)]
print [id(s) for s in l]
```

Result:

```
[34375618400, 34375618400, 34375618400, 34375626256]
```

P.S. I know about string interning :)

Comment: I think you should test it with variables, I suspect that these simple uses might be optimized at the compilation stage; my guess is that the `%s` form is always slower if the pattern is a variable string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small exercise:

```
>>> def f1():
    'hello'


>>> def f2():
    'hel' 'lo'


>>> def f3():
    'hel' + 'lo'


>>> def f4():
    'hel%s' % 'lo'


>>> def f5():
    'hel%s' % ('lo',)


>>> for f in (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5):
    print(f.__name__)
    dis.dis(f)


f1
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (None) 
              3 RETURN_VALUE         
f2
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (None) 
              3 RETURN_VALUE         
f3
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('hello') 
              3 POP_TOP              
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              7 RETURN_VALUE         
f4
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('hello') 
              3 POP_TOP              
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              7 RETURN_VALUE         
f5
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hel%s') 
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (('lo',)) 
              6 BINARY_MODULO        
              7 POP_TOP              
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, all simple concatenations/formatting are done by compiler. The last function requires more complex formatting and therefore, I guess, is actually executed. Since all those object created at compilation time they all have the same id.

Comment: So, if I typing code into Python console it is compiled first and after that interpreted?

Comment: @Roman: yes. Not much different from how you'd run a .py file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `%` is, technically speaking, string *formatting*, not concatenation. They are two entirely* different worlds.

If you know about string interning then you should know that there's absolutely no guarantee that two strings will occupy the same memory as another. The fact that in your example the first three do is nothing more than pure coincidence.

I'm not 100% sure how string formatting works, but I know that it's not implemented the same in the underlying C as concatenation  - I think it works a little more along the lines of `''.join(sequence)`, which is also faster than `+` for large strings - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join) for more info.

*sort of.

Comment: Ok, it's not concatenation, but used in the same way and return almost same result.

Comment: basically, yes. String concatenation should only be used for smaller strings and only a few occasions (after about 7 concatenation, it's much faster to use `''.join()`)