# Python- including a variable within the text part of parameters

Tags: python

So in Pygame have a function that displays messages to users:

```
def message_to_user(msg, color, X_displacement, Y_displacement):
    # creating function to display messages to the user
    message=font.render(msg,True,color)
    msgcenter=200+X_displacement,200+Y_displacement
    Game_display.blit(message,msgcenter)
```

now there is a message I need to display with another variable showing aswell:

```
        message_to_user("You managed to complete",levelcounter,"levels",green,0,40)
```

here is the error:

```
TypeError: message_to_user() takes exactly 4 arguments (6 given)
```

I understand why I am getting this error, just can't figure a way around it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371745/string-concatenation-in-python)

Comment: The error means what it says. Your function takes four arguments: msg, color, X_displacement, Y_displacement.

You've given six. Check out the duplicate link above for how to properly concatenate strings in Python so you only send the four arguments you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the string with the variable to make your message 1 argument

```
message_to_user("You managed to complete " + levelcounter + " levels",green,0,40)
```

This would fix the function call to make the arguments match the variables

Comment: And what would happen if `levelcounter` is not a string?

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate ‘str’ and ‘int’ objects. Would happen. So use Larry's answer of str(argument) to make it string

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the string before passing it to the function

```
mess = "You managed to complete {} levels".format(levelcounter)
message_to_user(mess, green, 0, 40)
```

Comment: ah such a simple solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this ...
message_to_user("You managed to complete",levelcounter,"levels",green,0,40)

should become...

message_to_user("You managed to complete" +str(levelcounter)+" levels",green,0,40)

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the `levelcounter` as an argument, and then create the `msg` within the definition.

```
def message_to_user(levelcounter, color, X_displacement, Y_displacement):
    msg = "You managed to complete " + str(levelcounter) + " levels!"
    message = font.render(msg, True, color)
    msgcenter = 200 + X_displacement, 200 + Y_displacement
    Game_display.blit(message, msgcenter)
```