# python:how to output the Dictionary key and value as the following style using python 2.6?

Tags: python, dictionary, csstidy

```
args =[]
csstidy_opts = {
    '--allow_html_in_templates':False,
    '--compress_colors':False,
    '--compress_font-weight':False,
    '--discard_invalid_properties':False,
    '--lowercase_s':false,
    '--preserve_css':false,
    '--remove_bslash':false,
    '--remove_last_;':false,
    '--silent':False,
    '--sort_properties':false,
    '--sort_selectors':False,
    '--timestamp':False,
    '--merge_selectors':2,  
}
for key value in csstidy_opts.item():
   args.append(key)
   args.append(':')
   args.append(value)
```

i want to output the string as follow:

"--allow_html_in_templates=false --compress_colors=false..."

if i add the condition, how to do:

if the value is false,the key and value would not output in the string(just only output the ture key and the others)

Comment: the last 4 lines of code you have there seem to be the solution already: you can simply take a string `csstidy=""` and add all map items as you proposed: `csstidy += "--"+key+"="+value+" "` under the condition that value equals `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
" ".join("%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in csstidy_opts.iteritems() if v is not False)
```

Not sure what exactly you mean about only outputting the "ture key", but this won't output things that are set to False in your input dictionary.

Edit:

If you need to put the arguments into args, you can do something pretty similar:

```
args = ["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in csstidy_opts.iteritems() if v is not False]
```

Comment: The exact answer I would have given as well.  +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
csstidy_opts = {
    '--allow_html_in_templates':False,
    '--compress_colors':False,
    '--compress_font-weight':False,
    '--discard_invalid_properties':False,
    '--lowercase_s':False,
    '--preserve_css':False,
    '--remove_bslash':False,
    '--remove_last_;':False,
    '--silent':False,
    '--sort_properties':False,
    '--sort_selectors':False,
    '--timestamp':False,
    '--merge_selectors':2,  
}

a = ""
for key,value in csstidy_opts.iteritems():    
    if value != False:
        a+=key+'='+str(value)+' '
 print a
```

output is

```
--merge_selectors=2
```

also note false need to be False

Comment: Multiple levels of string concatenation is not a recommended or efficient approach. Use the list comprension and string formatting from the other answer

Comment: @malbani,if i use `args = []`, how to so,and use `append` to push the key and the value into the array! i am a beginner for python,but i want to coding  the csstidy package for sublime Text 2!!

Comment: @jdi wow never realized python string concatenation was so much slower then .join. Here is a comparison i found after reading your comment [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join)