# Python writing to file multiple lines at once

Tags: python, io

I have a file with the following content.

```
1
2
3
```

Now I want to write 4,5 and 6 so that the file content will be like below

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Instead of writing 4,5 and 6 by doing `file.write("4" + '\n')`, `file.write("5" + '\n')`, `file.write("6" + '\n')`, how can I write all those last three number with just calling file.write command only once?

Update: I do not know in advance how many number I will be adding to the file. Numbers that will be added are stored in a giant list.

Comment: `file.write("4\n5\n6\n")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
file.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n" % (string1, string2, string3))
```

I'm assuming the strings you want to write are actually more complicated that a single number.

Update:

Since you don't know all the content you're writing ahead of time, you can do this:

```
stringToWrite = ""
for x in listOfNumbers:
    stringToWrite += x + "/n"

file.write(stringToWrite)
```

Comment: Zip: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20187027/355230) to a possibly related question might also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your strings don't end in newlines:

```
file.write('\n'.join(strings) + '\n')
```

If they do:

```
file.write(''.join(strings))
```

`strings` can be a list or tuple of string values, or anything else that's iterable containing string values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget newline is just another character:

```
file.write("4\n5\n6\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have '4', '5' and '6' as separate variables. If so, try this:

```
x='4'
y='5'
z='6'
file.write('\n'.join([x, y, z]) + '\n)
```