# Number Formatting in Python (Printing Number Left of Decimal)

Tags: python-2.7, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am trying to print whole numbers (number left of decimal point) with the following code:

```
print "Completed in %g".format(str(time_difference / 60), 1.0) + " minutes, %g".format(time_difference % 60, 1.0) + " seconds."
```

Instead I get:

```
Completed in %g minutes, %g seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print "Completed in {} minutes, {} seconds.".format(int(time_difference / 60), int(time_difference % 60))
```

Read more about the ["format" statement in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Also, avoid concatenating strings using "+". It is usually more efficient to [join list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join).

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing ways to print strings. To use `format`, refer to the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec). You have to use `{}`. For instance:

```
>>> print "Completed in {0:g} minutes, {1} seconds".format(time_difference % 60, 1.0)
Completed in 40 minutes, 1.0 seconds
```

To use the old notation, you have to use `%` to format. See [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> print "Completed in %g minutes, %g seconds" % (time_difference % 60, 1.0)
Completed in 40 minutes, 1 seconds
```