# change char in string by position

Tags: python, string, list

question is :
Write a function that accepts three parameters, a string and two integers.
The string represents a word in a guessing game. The two integer represent
positions to keep the letters as a starting point. The remaining letters should 
be replaced by the * symbol. The function should return the resulting string.

The doctests below should make this clear:

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):
    """
    >>> hangman_start("banana", 0, 5)
    'b****a'
    >>> hangman_start("passionfruit", 0, 7)
    'p******f****'
    >>> hangman_start("cherry", 3, 4)
    '***rr*'
    >>> hangman_start("peach", 2, 10)
    '**a**'
    >>> hangman_start("banana", -1, -1)
    '******'
    """
if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

I tried do this as below:

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):    
    count=0
    result=""
    while count<len(strng):
        if strng[count]==strng[pos1] or strng[count] == strng[pos2]:
             result += strng[count]
        else:
            result += "*"
        count+=1
    return result
```

but it does not work properly.
such as: `hangman_start("banana", 0, 5)` i got `ba*a*a`.

Any kind guy can help me with this?

Comment: You should actually check the `count` against the positions, not the characters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace all characters *except* on the provided positions by `*`:

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):
  return "".join([char if index in (pos1,pos2) else '*' for index, char in enumerate(strng)])

print hangman_start("asdasd", 3, 4)
```

The above prints

```
***as*
```

If you want to stick with your implementation, just replace the character-at-index comparison with just index comparison:

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):
  count=0
  result=""
  while count<len(strng):
    if count == pos1 or count == pos2:
      result += strng[count]
    else:
      result += "*"
    count+=1
  return result
```

While the input here is not large enough for it to matter, I'd like to suggest you append to a list and then `join` the list, rather than append to a string, as this is much, [much more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055541/1458374):

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):
  count=0
  result=[]
  while count<len(strng):
    if count == pos1 or count == pos2:
      result.append(strng[count])
    else:
      result.append("*")
    count+=1
  return "".join(result)
```

Like I said, the input is not large enough for it to matter in this case, but it's a good habit to adopt.

Comment: `if index in (pos1, pos2)` is even more concise

Comment: @Raniz absolutely, thanks for that! Delightful, making my list comprehensions less clunky significantly brightens up my day.

Comment: There is a special feeling to nailing those list/map comprehension one-liners =)

Answer (score 0):

```
def hangman_start(strng, pos1, pos2):    
    count=0
    result=""
    while count<len(strng):
        if count ==pos1 or count== pos2 :
             result += strng[count]
        else:
            result += "*"
        count+=1
    return result

h = hangman_start("banana", 0, 5)

print(h)
```

the solution is `if count ==pos1 or count== pos2 :`

o/p

```
b****a
```

you should compare the NUMERIC position values that you are passing

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong.

```
if strng[count]==strng[pos1] or strng[count] == strng[pos2]:
```

You here try to compare if char `strng[count]` in position `count` equals to the char `strng[pos1]` in position `pos1` or to the char `strng[pos2]` in `pos2`.

I think that's not you want.

Answer (score -1):

It should be

`if count==pos1 or count == pos2:`

and not

`if strng[count]==strng[pos1] or strng[count] == strng[pos2]:`