# How to write a string that could be None to '%s' to a file (python)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to write a string to a file. This file will be a query to Microsoft's SQL server, so it must follow a specific format. This is where my problem comes in.

Assuming the rest of the code is correct, I have my write method like so:

```
file.write("INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (int_value, string_value, comment)\n"
           "VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s')\n\n" 
           % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], row["comment"]))
```

As you can see, I need to put quotations around `%s` because that is the syntax of the query. I should also mention that I am developing a GUI. The user has the option to enter in a comment. If the user does not enter anything, `row["comment"]` will be None. However, because that I have quotations around `%s`, it will write `'None'`, which will be a string in the database as apposed to `None`, which translates into NULL in the database, which is what I want.

I could do something like this:

```
if row["comment"] is None:
    file.write("INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (int_value, string_value, comment)\n"
               "VALUES (%d, '%s', %s)\n\n" 
               % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], row["comment"]))
else:
    file.write("INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (int_value, string_value, comment)\n"
           "VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s')\n\n" 
           % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], row["comment"]))
```

but that's two lines of code. And what if later on I realize that more than one value could be None? I'll have to check every single case! I need to make this dynamic.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
comment_str = "None" if row["comment"] is None else "'{}'".format(row["comment"])
file.write("INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (int_value, string_value, comment)\n"
           "VALUES (%d, '%s', %s)\n\n" 
           % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], comment_str))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about not adding the quotes, and later substituting it with a comment that has the quotes (double substitution, but can be done in a single line)?

```
row = {"comment": "abc"}
comment = row.get("comment") # Note, bracket lookup would have thrown a KeyError, not returning None
values = "%d, '%s', %s" % (1, "string_value", "'%s'" % comment if comment is not None else None)
print values
```

Which will either print
`1, 'string_value', 'abc'` or `1, 'string_value', None`

Then just substitute values using `VALUES = (%s) % values`

Note that you actually don't even need to separate out VALUES into another substitution if you just keep

```
comment = row.get("comment")
# In your string:
VALUES = (%s) % ("%d, '%s', %s" % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], "'%s'" % comment if comment is not None else None))
```

Here's a basic example:

```
>>> comment = None
>>> 'Values = (%s)' % ("'%s'" % comment if comment is not None else None)
'Values = (None)'
>>> comment = "test"
>>> 'Values = (%s)' % ("'%s'" % comment if comment is not None else None)
"Values = ('test')"
>>> comment = "" # For empty comments, thanks to @Bharel for pointing this out
>>> 'Values = (%s)' % ("'%s'" % comment if comment is not None else None)
"Values = ('')"
```

Comment: In case of an empty comment, this will result in None.

Comment: @Bharel, and that's what we want right? Because if we get a `'None'` it gets treated as a string in the db (note, no quotes in `Values = (%s)`), but they get added if there is a comment). Edit oh nevermind, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @U Not entirely. We want empty comments to be empty, not `None`.

Comment: @Bharel, I see what you mean now, that makes sense, see edited answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use any python mysql module and its cursors option

```
cursor.mogrify(query, args)
```

if you are already using it.
It will properly escape everything depending on type.

If you want to do it manually then you can do a simple

```
row['comment'] if row['comment'] is None else "'".join(['',row['comment'],''])
```

before the query

Comment: In case of an empty comment, this will result in an error in the sql query, and it does not get the required result.

Comment: this works but instead of the join you may do this: `"'{}'".format(row['comment'])`

Comment: Sometimes join is faster. I know I know premature optimization, but still. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join

Comment: join will not be faster in this case, it will actually be much much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just insert

```
if row["comment"] is not None:
    row["comment"] = "'%s'" % row["comment"]

file.write(...
```

It gives you the custom behavior you want and doesn't require repeating any code

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just state ``if row["comment"]:`` as your first line? This will evaluate to ``True`` if ``row["comment"]`` is anything but ``None``.

Comment: @Igor `if row` will also happen in case of an empty comment. Not good.
Problem with this answer is that it edits the comment.

Comment: @Igor as Bharel says, that will map the empty string to "None", which is not Specified behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
file.write("INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TABLE (int_value, string_value, comment)\n"
       "VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s')\n\n" 
       % (row["int_value"], row["string_value"], row["comment"] or 'NULL'))
```

Comment: This does not get the required result. It formats it internally as `'NULL'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `repr(row["comment"])` with `%s`. It gives you quotes around a string, but leaves the `None` literal alone.

```
>>> 'VALUES (%s)' % repr(None)
'VALUES (None)'
>>> 'VALUES (%s)' % repr("string")
"VALUES ('string')"
```