# What is the most efficient and readable way to pass/format lots of variables to a large string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation, readability, code-readability

I have a couple "lengthy" lines like this one:

```
content = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n  <title>{0} - {1}</title>\n  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{3}/{2}.{4}\" />\n</head>\n<body>\n  <!-- layout... -->\n  <script type\"text/javascript\" src=\"{5}/{2}.{6}\"></script>\n</body>\n</html>\n".format(settings["app.name"], ncc, name, settings["dir"]["static.style"], settings["lang.style"], settings["dir"]["static.script"], settings["lang.script"])
```

Just by looking at such a line it you can tell that it is quite large and that it is in some ways hard to read and / or understand.

Is there a more efficient and readable way to dynamically insert lots of values into large strings?

Comment: you should take a look at jinja2 or mako... they're not specifically designed for strings, but for creating dynamic html pages/reports.

Comment: @Dot_Py thank you for the suggestion I will look into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to do:

```
content = (
    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  "
    "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n"
    "  <title>{0} - {1}</title>\n  "
    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{3}/{2}.{4}\" />\n</head>\n<body>\n"
    "  <!-- layout... -->\n  "
    "<script type\"text/javascript\" src=\"{5}/{2}.{6}\"></script>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
).format(
    settings["app.name"], ncc, name, settings["dir"]["static.style"],
    settings["lang.style"], settings["dir"]["static.script"],
    settings["lang.script"]
)
```

Note that there is no `,` at the end of each line.

However the best way to generate HTML is probably via some templating framework, e.g. jinja, mako, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I did not know you could do this. +1 I really appreciate the time and effort you put into it.

Comment: plus1 for jinja2 / mako option

Answer (score 0):

by having the strings in a list and then doing a join as in `' '.join(list)`. This will be a lot faster than simple concatenation.

`list = ["The quick brown", "fox"]
result = " ".join(list)`

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join) to see the difference is performance

Comment: Have you actually checked that it will be faster then raw string with `.format`? Cause it is **highly** unlikely.

Comment: Check the link I provided. You can see how many concats per second each approach does

Comment: Yes, the link you provided talks about `+` operator. That's absolutely not the case here. Please read questions carefuly next time.

Comment: the answer over there provides a link where there are a couple of methods compared. However you have a point I do not know how .format fits in the comparison. That being said I cannot image it is very fast because of the extra work it has to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, +1 I really appreciate the time and effort you put into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [multiline string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
args = (settings["app.name"], ncc, name, settings["dir"]["static.style"], 
        settings["lang.style"], settings["dir"]["static.script"], 
        settings["lang.script"])

content = """\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>{0} - {1}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{3}/{2}.{4}" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- layout... -->
  <script type"text/javascript" src="{5}/{2}.{6}"></script>
</body>
</html>""".format(args)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, +1 I really appreciate the time and effort you put into it.