# Concatenating Strings: str + str or "{:s}{:s}".format()?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is there any difference between

```
str_ = "foo" + "bar"
```

and

```
str_ = "{:s}{:s}".format("foo","bar")
```

or is it simply preference?

Comment: I recently read that + is faster for small strings.  But I think its a matter of style or readablility

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3055477/344286

Comment: `"foo" + "bar"` is converted to `"foobar"` by the compiler so the runtime cost is zero. A better comparison may be `foo = "foo";bar = "bar";str_ = foo + bar`.

Comment: `format` needs to parse the format string so for a simple concatenation of two strings, `+` is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

*Semantically?* No, both end up joining `"foo"` and `"bar"` and assigning them to `str`.

*Computationally?* Surely, Python will create the literal for `"foobar"` during compilation, the `str = "foo" + "bar"` assignment will be faster.

*From a readability aspect?* Again, `str = "foo" + "bar"` is surely more clear and concise.

---

The common errata in both your examples is that you're assigning to `str` which is a built-in name, so don't, you mask it.

Comment: I'm aware `str` is built in. Was just using it as a name. will change.

Comment: @socrates avoid that, it can lead to nasty situations which you don't need in your life :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the actual difference:

```
import dis

def concat():
    return 'foo' + 'bar'

def format():
    return '{}{}'.format('foo', 'bar')

dis.dis(concat)
print('*'*80)
dis.dis(format)
```

Comment: Similarly, just `dis.dis("'foo' + 'bar'")` and `dis.dis('"{:s}{:s}".format("foo","bar")')`.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Jim explanation, here's a little benchmark showing a comparison between both methods:

```
# measure execution time
import timeit

def f1(num_iterations):
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        value = "foo" + "bar"

def f2(num_iterations):
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        value = "{:s}{:s}".format("foo", "bar")

N = 100000000

print timeit.timeit('f1(N)', setup='from __main__ import f1, N', number=1)
print timeit.timeit('f2(N)', setup='from __main__ import f2, N', number=1)
```

The results in my laptop gives: f1=4.49492255239s and f2=47.5562411453s

So the conclusion is using format when N is big will be much slower than using the simpler str concatenation version.

Comment: This is a strange use of `timeit`. You've put the loop in the measurement and only run it once. For `f1` the cost of the loop is much larger than the cost of the line you are trying to time that its result is meaningless. `timeit('value = "foo" + "bar"')` would be the more standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Regards Jim answer, using `+` operator with many strings, can be slow.

Avoid doing something like this:

```
s = ' '
for p in parts:
    s += p
```

each `+=` operation create a new string. To avoid that, use `join()`.

```
' '.join(parts)
```

In your example, you don't need to use `+`. Simply place them adjacent  to each other with no +.

```
string = 'foo' 'bar'
print(string)
>"foobar"
```

Comment: Note that `"foo""bar"` *only* works for string literals, and happens at "compile" time.

Comment: @WayneWerner yep, like OP question.