# How Do I Get The Resulting Output?

Tags: python

I need a function that gives an output:

```
1111
    2222
        3333
```

This is what I got as a function:

```
def repeatNumber(someNumber):
    for i in range(0,someNumber):
        tabString = "\t"*i
        repeatingString = str(i+1)*4+"\n"
        finalString = tabString + repeatingString
        return finalString
```

But the output gives my only

```
1111
```

when I try to

```
print(repeatNumber(3))
```

at the end.

I know I have to add to a string, but I'm not quite sure what string(s) to add together...

Comment: `return` terminates the function; try `print`ing instead

Comment: When I use     print, I get an output of None at the very end of the string.. @Chris_Rands

Comment: Then don't print from the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning at the first iteraion of the loop. You can keep the result in a temporary variable and return that instead. Like this:

```
def repeatNumber(someNumber):
    return_string = ''
    for i in range(0,someNumber):
        tabString = "\t"*i
        repeatingString = str(i+1)*4+"\n"
        finalString = tabString + repeatingString
        return_string += finalString
    return return_string
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize to put the return_string = " " in the beginning of the function!

Comment: You'd be better off making a list that you join rather than using `+=` on strings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join

Comment: Never knew this! And it is faster by a margin. Makes sense to use `join`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: def repeatNumber(someNumber):
            for i in range(0,someNumber):
                tabString = "\t"*i
                repeatingString = str(i+1)*4+"\n"
                finalString = tabString + repeatingString
                print finalString

In [10]: repeatNumber(3)
1111

    2222

        3333
```

Comment: Oh wow! I haven't learned the In[] thing yet in class, but that seems very helpful! @manvi77

Comment: @aj2929 The "In[] thing " just means they're using Jupyter Notebook IPython