# I have a list and I want to print a range of it's content with range and for loop

Tags: python-3.6

I have the following list on python:

```
items = [5,4,12,7,15,9]
```

and I want to print in this form:

```
9,15,7,12,4
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: To print in without the first letter, replace (index + 1) with (index + 2) and it will exclude the first list element ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers_list = [5,4,12,7,15,9]

for index in range(len(numbers_list)):
  print(numbers_list[(index + 1) * - 1])
```

Not sure if it's very "Pythonic"

As the list indeces are being negated you can access the elements in the reverse order.

Last index in a Python is list [-1] and so on, till the first one being list length -1 (Plus one in this case to get the negative number closer to 0).

Comment: Can you please explain it?

Comment: First I got the length of list and then iterated over the range of it while multiplying indeces by -1 to make them negative and access the elements in the "reverse side".

Comment: but i want it till 4

Comment: Just make it (index + 2) It will exclude the first, but I guess you figured it out already ;)

Comment: Beside the fact the answer does not really solve the problem (as expected output is `9,15,7,12,4` and not `9\n15\n7\n12\n4`), this is not the best pythonic approach. Iterating through `range(len(` is unnecessary in this case, as you could change the original iterator by using `reversed(` or even `numbers_list[::-1]`.

Comment: @FunkySayu I think the dude that asked the question wanted the "Nonpythonic" solution as the question states: for loop and range.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reversed` and `str.join`:

```
numbers = [5, 4, 12, 7, 15, 9]
print(",".join(str(n) for n in reversed(numbers)))  # 9,15,7,12,4,5
```

`str.join` is by far better than building your own string using `mystring += "something"` in terms of performances. [How slow is Python's string concatenation vs. str.join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477) provides interesting insights about this.

I could also write a list comprehension to build an intermediate list like this:

```
reversed_string = [str(n) for n in reversed(numbers)]
print(",".join(reversed_string))
```

but writing list comprehension implies we store in-memory twice the list (the original one and the "strigified" one). Using a generator will dynamically compute the elements for `str.join`, somewhat the same way a classic iterator would do.