# Sum of list with any type of items

Tags: python, list

I'm learning python and our teacher told us to write a function that will return the sum of a list no matter what the type of its values are.

If the list is Integers, then: `sum([1, 4, 5, 6]) = 16`

If the list is Strings, then: `sum(['a','b',c']) = 'abc'`

The list can also be made of tuples and lists inside of it.

The code needs to be as short and simple as possible. I tried writing this:

```
element = list[0]
for thing in list:
    for thingy in thing:
        element += thingy
print element
```

but it isn't working.. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why does it not work?

Comment: with numbers the error is: 'int' object is not iterable,
with strings the string has the first element twice. and with tuples and lists I get more errors

Comment: So, just do: `for thing in list: element += thing`. Why the second loop?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Because there could be a list inside a list. I also need to sum all the values inside the inner list

Comment: Is it possible for the nesting depth to be 2 at most?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, no more than 2

Comment: Okay, and can `itertools` be used here?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. `list()` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html), which you overwrite with your script. And tell your teacher, s/he should teach you Python3.

Comment: I know. it was just an example to show here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I should point out your mistake with initialising `element` to `list[0]`... you'll be adding it *twice*.

So, to solve this problem, my first instinct is to start with -

```
def generic_sum(data):
    return sum(data, type(data[0])())
```

But this only works for integers and floats, lists and tuples, and `Counter` objects (strings also have a `__add__` method but `sum` special cases them).

So, we'll need a more general solution that should work for, hopefully any type of data.

---

Here's one, but you'll need to take care of the fact that your list elements can be arbitrarily nested. My approach would be to *first* flatten your data, and *then* sum its elements.

A naive approach would be -

```
flat_data = [y for x in data for y in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
```

Which you can also write as:

```
flat_data = []
for x in data:
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        x = [x]
    flat_data.extend(x)
```

And then,

```
init = flat_data[0]
for v in flat_data[1:]:
    init += v
```

Putting this into a function, you have -

```
def generic_sum(data):
    flat_data = [y for x in data for y in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]

    sum_ = flat_data[0]   # don't use `sum`, you hide the builtin that way
    for v in flat_data[1:]:
        sum_ += v

    return sum_
```

Here's a demo on some sample input -

```
>>> generic_sum([[1], 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]])
21
```

```
>>> generic_sum(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']])
'abcd'
```

---

If you're looking for efficiency, I'd recommend two things here -

1. using `sum` for numeric values, instead of manually adding them up with a loop, and
2. *special casing* strings, by calling `str.join` on them, instead of summing them up.

```
def generic_sum_opt(data):
     flat_data = [y for x in data for y in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
     return sum(flat_data) if not isinstance(flat_data[0], str) else ''.join(flat_data)
```

Which works just the same as above, but should be more efficient for *string concatenation*.

```
>>> generic_sum_opt([[1], 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]])
21
```

```
>>> generic_sum_opt(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']])
'abcd'
```

**Note**

- For python2, use `isinstance(flat_data[0], basestring)` instead (because you can have `str` or `unicode` objects).
- Calling `str.join` is computationally cheaper (linear time) than summing each character (quadratic time). This is a consequence of the fact that strings are immutable.

---

**Benchmarks**

```
data = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']] * 1000000
```

```
%timeit generic_sum(data)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.83 s per loop
```

```
%timeit generic_sum_opt(data)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop
```

Both methods cross a second when dealing with millions of elements. I'd attribute this to the flattening step. Alternatively, let's time just summation code on flat data.

```
flat_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] * 1000000
```

```
%%timeit
sum_ = flat_data[0]   # don't use `sum`, you hide the builtin that way
for v in flat_data[1:]:
     sum_ += v

1 loop, best of 3: 623 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit ''.join(flat_data)
10 loops, best of 3: 35.5 ms per loop
```

This makes more sense, and is better indicative of the gross inefficiency of concatenating strings within a loop.

Furthermore, `generic_sum_opt` is faster with summing numbers.

```
data = [[1], 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]] * 1000000
```

```
%timeit generic_sum(data)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.94 s per loop
```

```
%timeit generic_sum_opt(data)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.53 s per loop
```

The second function is definitely faster thanks to the use of `sum` there.

Comment: @coldspeed why is that (quadtratic time)

Comment: @MukulSharma Each time you add a string to another, you have to allocate new memory, which linear, and is wasteful. You perform a linear operation linear number of times, and so it is quadratic.

Comment: @MukulSharma string concatenation requires the creation of an entirely new string, every time.

Comment: @coldspeed and how join avoid that

Comment: @MukulSharma Since you asked, a lot of hardwork has been poured into that function to optimise it for efficiency. The crux of it is that, memory is allocated once, and is linear (a bit iffy on the details though). This Q&A provides a good perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer! this helped a lot

Comment: It seems `y` in the list comprehension contains a list, but how come it's behaving like `extend()`, not just like a nested list inside the base list; trying hard to understand this part and failing :(

Comment: @heemayl It's a common flattening idiom. This is a nested list comprehension. The condition `(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])` will control this.

Comment: Hmm but only getting flattening when using a genexp, not when using a list comprehension. Thats what bothering me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the builtin `sum`, which requires integers or floats throughout the list or tuple, you can use `reduce`:

```
s1 = [1, 4, 5, 6]
s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, s1))
print(reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, s2))
```

Output:

```
16
abc
```

In Python3, `functools` is required to use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, s1))
```

**Edit**: to sum the values of nested lists, it may be best to use recursion, as the list could be of arbitrary depth:

```
def flatten(l):
   return reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, [i if not isinstance(i, list) else flatten(i) for i in l])

print(flatten([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', ['h', ['18', 'dd', 'b']]]]))
```

Output:

```
abcdeh18ddb
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about that function. Would it would for inner lists and tuples?

Comment: @eitanmayer supposing the nested list was `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`. What is your desired output from that list? `['abc', 'def']`, or `'abcdef'`?

Comment: abcdef - the function should everything into one

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you are concatenating/summing first element twice

**example:-**
lets say `listy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
& `element = listy[0] = 1`

**Now for first iteration**
    `element = element + thingy (1 + 1)`, since thingy for first iteration also points to `listy[0]`

Just check the type of element of list:-

**for e.g.**

```
if isinstance(string, list[0]) :
    sum = ""
elif isinstance(int, list[0]):
    sum = 0
else :
    // raise some error
for i in listy:
    sum += i
```