# How is the string.join(str_list, ''") implemented under the hood in Python?

Tags: python

I know that concatenating two strings using the `+=` operator makes a new copy of the old string and then concatenates the new string to that, resulting in quadratic time complexity.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join) gives a nice time comparison between the `+=` operation and `string.join(str_list, '')`. It looks like the `join()` method runs in linear time (correct me if I am wrong). Out of curiosity, I wanted to know how the `string.join(str_list, '')` method is implemented in Python since strings are immutable objects?

Comment: `.join()` only accept one parameter

Comment: str.join(iterable), so join method takes any Iterable object not only list of strings

Answer (score 1):

It's implemented in C, so python mutability is less important. You can find the appropriate source here: [unicodeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c)