# Joining an element, beginning with small letter, to a previous element of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Stackoverflow, hello

I have a specific task now. It concerns a uniting elements into a list and also checking for a lower letter.

So, I have a hierarchical list with lists inside:

```
ingridient_names_final=[['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy', 'sauce'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda', 'cheese'], ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'pepper', 'Pita', 'bread', 'Wine', 'vinegar', 'Tomato']]
```

Which should be transformed to:

```
[['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy sauce'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda cheese'], ['Beef', 'Sweet pepper', 'Pita bread', 'Wine vinegar', 'Tomato']]
```

So, words "sause", "cheese", "pepper", "bread" and "vinegar" I need to join to the previous element of the list.

I understood only that method `islower()` should be used here:

```
for element in ingridient_names_final:
    # print (element)
    for element2 in element:
        # print (element2)
        if element2.islower():
            print(element2)
```

An the result is:

```
sauce
cheese
pepper
bread
vinegar
```

But how can I join them to the previous element of the each small list inside the original one? I am a beginner in this language, please, help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

for lst in ingridient_names_final:
    new_lst = []
    for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda s: s[0].islower()):
        if k:
             new_lst[-1] += ' ' + ' '.join(g)
        else:
             new_lst.extend(g)
    lst[:] = new_lst
```

Or even simpler:

```
for lst in ingridient_names_final:
    new_lst = []
    for s in lst:
        if s[0].islower():
            new_lst[-1] += ' ' + s
        else:
            new_lst.append(s)
    lst[:] = new_lst
```

Answer (score 0):

regex version solution:

```py
import re

ingredient_names_final = [['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'],
                          ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy', 'sauce'],
                          ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda', 'cheese'],
                          ['Beef', 'Sweet', 'pepper', 'Pita', 'bread', 'Wine',
                           'vinegar', 'Tomato']]


print([
    re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z ]*(?![A-Z])', ' '.join(ingredient))
    for ingredient in ingredient_names_final
])
```

output:

```py
[['Egg', 'Milk', 'Tomato'], ['Duck', 'Water', 'Honey', 'Soy sauce'], ['Potato', 'Garlic', 'Gouda cheese'], ['Beef', 'Sweet pepper', 'Pita bread', 'Wine vinegar', 'Tomato']]
```

Or following regex works, too.

```py
print([
    re.split(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', ' '.join(ingredient))
    for ingredient in ingredient_names_final
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many concatenations you want to perform and if you can have a lot of consecutive lowercased words, then you should take care about the fact that strings are immutable in Python.

More info about performance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join).
So as an alternative to the valid solution proposed above, here is one using `str.join`.

```
result = []
for ingredients_list in ingridient_names_final:
    next_idx = 0
    count = 0
    new_ingredients_list = []

    while next_idx < len(ingredients_list) - 1:
        if ingredients_list[next_idx + 1].islower():
            count += 1
            next_idx += 1
            continue
        # Avoid numerous string concatenations
        ingredient = ' '.join(ingredients_list[next_idx - count: next_idx + 1])
        new_ingredients_list.append(ingredient)
        count = 0
        next_idx += 1
    new_ingredients_list.append(' '.join(ingredients_list[next_idx - count: next_idx + 1]))

    result.append(new_ingredients_list)
```