# Python: Getting all strings inside dictionary structure

Tags: python, string, dictionary, unicode, key-value-store

WARNING: This is still Python 2.7!

For some reason the following function has extremely slow runtime:

```
def get_content(d,content):
    if isinstance(d,unicode):
        content += d
        content += u'\n'
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        for key in d:
            content += get_content(d[key],content)
    elif isinstance(d,list):
        for el in d:
            content += get_content(el,content)
    return content

content = get_content(D,u'')
```

That is although `D` is quite small. Nothing crazy going on there size-wise.

Do you see what the problem is or what would be a better way to solve the task?

EDIT: I changed the code to ...

```
def get_content(d,content):
    if isinstance(d,unicode):
        content += [d]
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        for key in d:
            content += get_content(d[key],content)
    elif isinstance(d,list):
        for el in d:
            content += get_content(el,content)
    return content

content = get_content(D,[])
```

... and it still has the same problem.

Comment: How many hours does it run on your machine?

Comment: No, it's getting slower and slower something must be wrong with the recursion or there is some side-effect of the unicode that I am not aware of. The input XML is only 150KB large and then I am using xmltodict to make it to a dictionary and now I was trying to get the string contents. It's really small.

Comment: there is no base case in your recursion

Comment: Repeated string concatenation is not recommended. Try appending your data to a list and using `'\n'.join(your_list)` at the end. Currenlty each time you concatenate strings the whole string has to be recreated in memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join

Comment: @bigbounty What is a base case?

Comment: @bigbounty: `return content` is the base case when all `if` and `elif` don't match or when `isinstance(d,unicode)`

Comment: @RadioControlled: a case where the recursion ends, i.e. `get_content()` is not called any more.

Comment: That's a good point though, maybe the problem has something to do with that. I am not that unexperienced in python and I am really puzzled at the moment ;)

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing an empty list for all `get_content` calls? e.g. only append the 'new' stuff

Comment: @ScootCork You solved the mystery! Is this worth writing an answer for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are reappending the whole content at each recursion. To solve pass an empty list to each `get_content` call instead.

```
def get_content(d,content):
    if isinstance(d,unicode):
        content += [d]
    elif isinstance(d,dict):
        for key in d:
            content += get_content(d[key],[])
    elif isinstance(d,list):
        for el in d:
            content += get_content(el,[])
    return content

content = get_content(D,[])
```