# Most efficient way to concatenate words from a big CSV file: pandas or Python standard library?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-data, word-cloud

I'm trying to do a textual analysis and have collected my data into a CSV document with three columns. I'm trying to combine all the text from the second column into a single string to perform some word analysis (word cloud, frequency etc.) I've imported the CSV file using pandas. In the code below, `data` is a `DataFrame` object.

```
# Extract words from comment column in data
words = " "
for msg in data["comment"]:
     msg = str(msg).lower()
     words = words + msg + " "
print("Length of words is:", len(words))
```

The output gets parsed using [word_cloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud).

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 3000, height = 2000, random_state=1, collocations=False, stopwords = stopwordsTerrier.union(stopwordsExtra)).generate(words)
```

#### CSV File

```
rating, comment, ID
5, Itâ€™s just soooo delicious but silly price and postage price, XXX1
5, Love this salad dressing... One my kids will estvðŸ˜Š, XXX2
...
```

The code works fine for smaller files <240kb etc., but I am recently working with a 50mb file and this has slowed down the script by a lot (179,697 rows) - I'm not sure if it will even finish computing. I am sure that this is the bottleneck because I'm running the script in Jupyter notebook and this is the only code in the cell I am executing.

My question is: Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What type of object is `data`? What type of object is `data['comment']`? Are you sure the *bottleneck* is the loop in your example? 50 Mb file is how many rows?

Comment: I'll edit the question to include that info

Comment: Done. 'data'  is a pandas dataframe, data.dtypes returns data['comment'] as an object. I think it should be bottleneck as I am executing just those lines in a Jupyter cell, and 50mb is around 179k rows.

Comment: `words = " ".join(data["comment"].str.lower()` ? But do you really want them in a giant string? Sounds more like you looking to tokenize a corpus of documents?

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-string-methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-string-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pandas solution (2.5 times faster than standard library)

A Pandas Series can be converted to a string with: [**pandas.Series.str.cat**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas-series-str-cat)

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
words = data["comment"].str.cat(sep=' ').lower()
```

## Python standard library solution (slower)

```
import csv

comment_list = []
with open(file_path, newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        comment_list.append(row["comment"])
words = " ".join(comment_list).lower()
```

## Performance testing

### Read CSV using standard library vs. `pandas.read_csv`

Using `pandas.read_csv()` is at least 2.5 times faster than the Python standard library package `csv`.

#### Create a test CSV file: test_data.csv

```
import random

reviews = [
    "Love this salad dressing... One my kids will estvðŸ˜Š",
    "Itâ€™s just soooo delicious but silly price and postage price",
    "The sitcome was entertaining but still a waste of time",
    "If only I had ten stomaches to enjoy everything the buffet had to offer"
]

with open("test_data.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write("random_number,comment,index\n")
    for i in range(10000):
        file.write(f"{random.randint(0, 9)},{random.choice(reviews)},{i}\n")
```

#### Read CSV file 100 times

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import timeit

def read_csv_stnd(file_path: str) -> str:
    comment_list = []
    with open(file_path, newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            comment_list.append(row["comment"])
    return " ".join(comment_list).lower()

def read_csv_pandas(file_path: str) -> str:
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    return data["comment"].str.cat(sep=' ').lower()

data_file = "test_data.csv"
print(f"Time to run read_csv_stnd 100 times: {timeit.timeit(lambda: read_csv_stnd(data_file), number=100)}")
print(f"Time to run read_csv_pandas 100 times: {timeit.timeit(lambda: read_csv_pandas(data_file), number=100)}")
```

#### Results of reading CSV file:

```
Time to run read_csv_stnd 100 times: 2.349453884999093
Time to run read_csv_pandas 100 times: 0.9676197949993366
```

### Standard library `lower()` vs. `pandas.Series.str.lower`

Using the standard library function `lower()` is roughly 5 times faster than using `pandas.Series.str.lower`

#### `pandas.Series.str.lower`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> s = pd.Series(['lower', 'CAPITALS', 'this is a sentence', 'SwApCaSe'])
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: s.str.lower().str.cat(sep=' '), number=10000)
1.9734079910012952
```

#### `lower()`

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: s.str.cat(sep=' ').lower(), number=10000)
0.3571630870010267
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new string in every iteration, you can try to append the word to a list, and then transform the list into a string. Maybe with something like:

```
words = [word.lower() for word in data["comment"]]
words = " ".join(words)
```

I've tested it with 100,000 words and it seems to be roughly 15 times faster than the method you are currently working with. Of course you can add a space at the beginning of the string or do other modifications to match your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious improvement is concatenating python string as below (This is a pythonic way):

`words = " ".join((str(msg).lower() for msg in data["comment"]))`

The way you use generates new string on each concatenation because strings are immutable in python.

You can find more info [here](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join#:%7E:text=String%20join%20is%20significantly%20faster%20then%20concatenation.&text=Strings%20are%20immutable%20and%20can,a%20concatenation%20of%20the%20two)