# How to generate a random string without characters pertaining to a list, such as ','?

Tags: python, list

Here is the code that I have used and reference in this post:

```
alpha=["One", "Two", "Three"]
beta=["One", "Two", "Three"]
charlie=["One", "Two", "Three"]
import random
alpharandom=random.randint(0,2)
betarandom=random.randint(0,2)
charlierandom=random.randint(0,2)
stringcode=(alpha[alpharandom],beta[betarandom],charlie[charlierandom])
stringcodetwo=str(stringcode).replace(" ", "")
print(stringcodetwo)
```

I am using python 3.0 to generate a random string using predefined items from lists.  This results in an output similar to:

```
('Two','One','Two')
```

However, would it be possible to generate so that the brackets, commas and quotation marks are omitted? I have tried the `replace` function, but that only seems to work for the spaces between the generated string.
An example of a desired output would be:

```
TwoOneTwo
```

Comment: `print(alpha[alpharandom] + beta[betarandom] + charlie[charlierandom])`

Comment: @shahkalpesh Thanks! This works. I'm pretty sure there's no way to accept your comment yet, but I would've if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.join` string method instead of `replace`.

Instead of: `stringcodetwo=str(stringcode).replace(" ", "")`

Do: `stringcodetwo="".join(stringcode)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your output has brackets and commas is that you are printing a tuple.

```
stringcode=(alpha[alpharandom],beta[betarandom],charlie[charlierandom])
```

This line is creating a tuple of 3 strings.

There are many ways to join the string values to make a single string.

Any easy way would be:

```
"".join(stringcode)
```

Essentially it iterates through the values of the iterable (the tuple `stringcode` in this case) and joins them into a string separated by `""` (so just joins the strings with nothing in between)

You could also just directly create a string instead of a tuple (if that's what you need):

```
stringcode = alpha[alpharandom] + beta[betarandom] + charlie[charlierandom]
print (stringcode)
```

As each of the individual elements are strings, we are just concatenating them and storing them in `stringcode`.

For which method is better, this question can provide some insight: [How slow is Python's string concatenation vs. str.join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join)

Read more about tuples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and join in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop to iterate over a set and with the use of end ="". you can remove the newline.

```
alpha=["One", "Two", "Three"]
beta=["One", "Two", "Three"]
charlie=["One", "Two", "Three"]
import random
alpharandom=random.randint(0,2)
betarandom=random.randint(0,2)
charlierandom=random.randint(0,2)
stringcode=(alpha[alpharandom],beta[betarandom],charlie[charlierandom])
for i in range(len(stringcode)):
  print(stringcode[i], end="")
```