# how to replace uppercase and lowercase letters in words alternately in a sentence? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, uppercase, lowercase

I am new to Python programming. I'm trying to learn about lists.

I want to create a new program that can convert each word into uppercase and lowercase letters alternately in a sentence.

I’m stuck here:

```
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
result = ""
myArr = input_text.split(' ')

for idx in range(len(myArr)):
  if idx % 2 == 0 :
    result = result + myArr[idx].upper()
  else:
    result = result + myArr[idx].lower()

print(str(result))
```

With this code I can get, for example:

```
input : "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
output : "HELLOmyNAMEisRAHULandI'MfromINDIA"
```

but what I am trying to get is:

```
input : "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
output : "HELLO my NAME is RAHUL and I'M from INDIA"
```

I want to add a space to each word in the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've sort of got it -- the best way to do this is to add the capitalized/lowercased words to a list, then use `.join()` to turn the word list into a string with each word separated by a space:

```py
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
result = ""
myArr = input_text.split(' ')
words = []
for idx in range(len(myArr)):
  if idx % 2 == 0 :
    words.append(myArr[idx].upper())
  else:
    words.append(myArr[idx].lower())

result = ' '.join(words)
print(result)
```

Contrary to what other answerers have suggested, [using repeated concatenation is a bad idea for efficiency reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join).

Comment: Hey, Thank you! it worked, it really helped me.

Comment: result is already a `str`, so last statement should be just - `print(result)`  No need to convert to string again.

Comment: You’re right. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension we can try:

```py
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
words = input_text.split()
output = ' '.join([x.upper() if ind % 2 == 0 else x for ind, x in enumerate(words)])
print(output)  # HELLO my NAME is RAHUL and I'M from INDIA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add all the values to a list and finally join them using the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) method.

```py
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
result = []
myArr = input_text.split(' ')

for idx in range(len(myArr)):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        res = myArr[idx].upper()
    else:
        res = myArr[idx].lower()
    result.append(res)

print(" ".join(result))
```

Output:

```
HELLO my NAME is RAHUL and I'M from INDIA
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you! it worked, it really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I provided another type of answers here using `enumerate` (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/), which loop a list (or tuple) with its index:

```
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"

result = []
for idx, word in enumerate(input_text.split()):
    result.append(word.upper() if idx % 2 == 0 else word.lower())
print(' '.join(result))
```

The answer also can be shorter like this using List Comprehension (see [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension))

```
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"

result = [word.upper() if idx % 2 == 0 else word.lower() for idx, word in enumerate(input_text.split())]
print(' '.join(result))
```

It would be helpful to know for your Python life :)

Answer (score 1):

I have added space where you are appending to the list:

```
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
result = ""
myArr = input_text.split(' ')

for idx in range(len(myArr)):
    if idx % 2 == 0 :
        result = result + myArr[idx].upper() + " "  # added a space
    else:
        result = result + myArr[idx].lower() + " "  # added a space

print(str(result))
```

This gives:

```
HELLO my NAME is RAHUL and I'M from INDIA
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you! it worked, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a space to the result after adding each word, i.e.

```
result = result + ' '
```

This will also add a space at the end of the string, which may not be desirable. You can remove it with the rstrip() function:

```
result = result.rstrip()
```

By the way, result is already a string, so you don't need to cast it to a string for the print statement.

So, put it all together:

```
input_text = "hello my name is rahul and i'm from india"
result = ""
myArr = input_text.split(' ')

for idx in range(len(myArr)):
  if idx % 2 == 0 :
    result = result + myArr[idx].upper()
  else:
    result = result + myArr[idx].lower()
  result = result + ' '

result = result.rstrip()    

print(result)
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you! it worked, it really helped me.