# How to replace last character in nested loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, string-concatenation

I'm trying to get output to display your inputted numbers in words:

```py
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six",
    "7": "Seven",
    "8": "Eight",
    "9": "Nine"
}
output = ""
for character in phone:
    output += digits_mapping.get(character) + ", "
print(output, end="")
```

For example, if input is equal to `545`, I will get `Five, Four, Five,`

How do i get `Five, Four, Five!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another strategy - check to see if you are on the last item in the list. If you are, append "!" - otherwise, append ", ".

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six",
    "7": "Seven",
    "8": "Eight",
    "9": "Nine"
}
output = ""
for i in range(len(phone)):
  if i == len(phone) - 1:
    output += digits_mapping.get(phone[i]) + "!"
  else:
    output += digits_mapping.get(phone[i]) + ", "
    
print(output, end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in loops is generally a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3055477/13944524) in Python (Not so bad when doing it a few times). Instead you can use a list and append the items to it. Then use `.join()`. For printing you need to specify the `end=` argument to `'!\n'` instead of the default `'\n'`.

```py
output = [digits_mapping[char] for char in phone]
print(", ".join(output), end='!\n')
```

You could also use generator expression:

```py
print(", ".join(digits_mapping[char] for char in phone), end='!\n')
```

Another way is to build the string with `'!'` then use normal print:

```py
print(", ".join(digits_mapping[char] for char in phone) + '!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you are creating a character delimited list, it's best writing the members of the list to a list object and the using `join()` to output the delimited string. This is true in any language (although it's usually an array, not a list, that you use). Instead:

```
phone = input("Phone: ")
digits_mapping = {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six",
    "7": "Seven",
    "8": "Eight",
    "9": "Nine"
}
words = []
for character in phone:
    words.append(digits_mapping.get(character))    
print(",".join(words) + "!", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end just print a copy of the string, with the exception of the last 2 characters (a space and a comma: ", "), and add to your end parameter the exclamation sign you desire. Your last line would look like this:

```
print(output[:-2], end="!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that after the `for`, you reassign `output` to itself omitting the last character(","). Then you concatenate `output` with "!".

```
output=output[0:len(output)-1]
output+="!"
```

I hope that I helped you. Have a nice coding session.