# Is there a lazy/iterator equivalent to `str.split()`?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a generator version of `string.split()` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862010/is-there-a-generator-version-of-string-split-in-python)

`str.split(delim)` splits a string into a list of tokens, separated by `delim`. The entire list of tokens is returned in one hit.

When dealing with large blocks of text, it might be advantageous to process tokens lazily. That is, only get one token at a time, as needed. (The example that springs to mind is processing a large chunk of text in memory.)

Is there a builtin or a standard library function that will perform a lazy `split()`? Something from `itertools`?

Comment: I have just posted a new answer in the duplicate which was not there before, since I think you can use `re.finditer()`, which would not consume any extra memory http://stackoverflow.com/a/9770397/711085

Answer (score 3):

Not exact equivalent, but `re.finditer()` searches string lazily.