# how to extract the word before a certain word in a python string

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a `df` of python strings:

```
  string
0 this house has 3 beds inside 
1 this is a house with 2 beds in it
2 the house has 4 beds
```

I want to extract how many beds each house has. I felt a good way to do this would be to just find the item before `beds`.

While attempting to complete this problem, I of course noticed strings are indexed by character. That means I would have to turn the strings into a list with `str.split(' ')`.

Then, I can find the index of 'beds' in each of the strings, and return the previous index. I tried both a list comprehension and `df.iterrows()` for this and can't seem to figure out the right way to do it. My desired output is:

```
  string                            beds
0 this house has 3 beds inside        3
1 this is a house with 2 beds in it   2
2 the house has 4 beds                4
```

Answer (score 0):

look at [efficient way to get words before and after substring in text (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897436/efficient-way-to-get-words-before-and-after-substring-in-text-python)

In your case, you could do

```
for index, row in df.iterrrows(): 
    row['beds'] = row['string'].partition('bed')[0].strip()[-1]
```

The `partition` function splits the string based on a word and returns a `tuple`
The `strip` function is just used to remove white spaces.
If everything works, then the number you are looking for will be at the end of the first value of the tuple. Hence the `[0]`

```
for index, row in df.iterrrows(): 
    row['beds'] = row['string'].partition('bed')[0].strip()[-1]
```

If the above code is broken down for better readability:

```
for index, row in df.iterrrows(): 
    split_str = row['string'].partition('bed')
    word_before_bed = split_str[0].strip()
    number_of_beds = word_before_bed[-1]
    row['beds'] = number_of_beds #append column to existing row

print(df.head())
```

The output `df` will have a 3 columns.

Note: this is a quick "hack". Notice there is no error checking in the loop. You should add error checking as you never know if the word "bed" shows up at all in the row.

Comment: Couldn't this just be a vectorized operation instead of looping over the dataframe?