# Conditionals on replacement in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, string-substitution

So I may have a string 'Bank of China', or 'Embassy of China', and 'International China'

I want to replace all country instances except when we have an 'of ' or 'of the '

Clearly this can be done by iterating through a list of countries, checking if the name contains a country, then checking if before the country 'of ' or 'of the ' exists.

If these do exist then we do not remove the country, else we do remove country. The examples will become:

'Bank of China', or 'Embassy of China', and 'International'

However iteration can be slow, particularly when you have a large list of countries and a large lists of texts for replacement.

Is there a faster and more conditionally based way of replacing the string? So that I can still use a simple pattern match using the Python re library?

My function is along these lines:

```
def removeCountry(name):
    for country in countries:
        if country in name:
            if 'of ' + country in name:
                return name
            if 'of the ' + country in name:
                return name
            else:
                name =  re.sub(country + '$', '', name).strip()
                return name
    return name
```

EDIT: I did find some info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). This does describe how to do an if, but I really want a 
if not 'of '
if not 'of the '
then replace...

Comment: Is there a reason you need to accomplish both the conditional and substitution in one single regular expression? Or, is this an abstract example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile a few sets of regular expressions, then pass your list of input through them. Something like:
    import re

```
countries = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
takes = [re.compile(r'of\s+(the)?\s*%s$' % (c), re.I) for c in countries]
subs = [re.compile(r'%s$' % (c), re.I) for c in countries]

def remove_country(s):
    for regex in takes:
        if regex.search(s):
            return s
    for regex in subs:
        s = regex.sub('', s)
    return s

print remove_country('the bank of foo')
print remove_country('the bank of the baz')
print remove_country('the nation bar')

''' Output:
    the bank of foo
    the bank of the baz
    the nation
'''
```

It doesn't look like anything faster than linear time complexity is possible here. At least you can avoid recompiling the regular expressions a million times and improve the constant factor.

Edit: I had a few typos, bu the basic idea is sound and it works. I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a good solution. Also I can speed it up by initially checking if a country even exists in s

Comment: @redrubia Are you sure this solution is okay? I just tested it and it looks like it doesn't return the correct result: `remove_country('Embassy of China')` results in `''` (empty string). Instead of `regex.match(s)` it should be `regex.find(s)`. (And `regex.replace` should be `regex.sub`).

Comment: Pardon: `re.search(s)`.

Comment: yeah this is incorrect answer, just tried it too and seems it produces a null string

Comment: Couple of typos, yes. I guess you're looking for a plug and play solution... Anyway it works and I've posted copy-pasteable code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the approach in [Python: how to determine if a list of words exist in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718345/python-how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-words-exist-in-a-string/21742190#21718896) to find any countries mentioned, then do further processing from there.

Something like

```
countries = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antigua",
    "Arabia",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bahrain",
    "China",
    "Russia"
    # etc
]

def find_words_from_set_in_string(set_):
    set_ = set(set_)
    def words_in_string(s):
        return set_.intersection(s.split())
    return words_in_string

get_countries = find_words_from_set_in_string(countries)
```

then

```
get_countries("The Embassy of China in Argentina is down the street from the Consulate of Russia")
```

returns

```
set(['Argentina', 'China', 'Russia'])
```

... which obviously needs more post-processing, but very quickly tells you exactly what you need to look for.

As pointed out in the linked article, you must be wary of words ending in punctuation - which could be handled by something like `s.split(" \t\r\n,.!?;:'\"")`. You may also want to look for adjectival forms, ie "Russian", "Chinese", etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function accepts a function as replacement text, which is called in order to get the text that should be substituted in the given match. So you could do this:

```
import re

def make_regex(countries):
    escaped = (re.escape(country) for country in countries)
    states = '|'.join(escaped)
    return re.compile(r'\s+(of(\sthe)?\s)?(?P<state>{})'.format(states))

def remove_name(match):
    name = match.group()
    if name.lstrip().startswith('of'):
        return name
    else:
        return name.replace(match.group('state'), '').strip()

regex = make_regex(['China', 'Italy', 'America'])
regex.sub(remove_name, 'Embassy of China, International Italy').strip()
# result: 'Embassy of China, International'
```

The result might contain some spurious space (in the above case a last `strip()` is needed). You can fix this modifying the regex to:

```
\s*(of(\sthe)?\s)?(?P<state>({}))
```

To catch the spaces before `of` or before the country name and avoid the bad spacing in the output.

Note that this solution can handle a whole text, not just text of the form `Something of Country` and `Something Country`. For example:

```
In [38]: regex = make_regex(['China'])
    ...: text = '''This is more complex than just "Embassy of China" and "International China"'''

In [39]: regex.sub(remove_name, text)
Out[39]: 'This is more complex than just "Embassy of China" and "International"'
```

an other example usage:

```
In [33]: countries = [
    ...:     'China', 'India', 'Denmark', 'New York', 'Guatemala', 'Sudan',
    ...:     'France', 'Italy', 'Australia', 'New Zealand', 'Brazil', 
    ...:     'Canada', 'Japan', 'Vietnam', 'Middle-Earth', 'Russia',
    ...:     'Spain', 'Portugal', 'Argentina', 'San Marino'
    ...: ]

In [34]: template = 'Embassy of {0}, International {0}, Language of {0} is {0}, Government of {0}, {0} capital, Something {0} and something of the {0}.'

In [35]: text = 100 * '\n'.join(template.format(c) for c in countries)

In [36]: regex = make_regex(countries)
    ...: result = regex.sub(remove_name, text)

In [37]: result[:150]
Out[37]: 'Embassy of China, International, Language of China is, Government of China, capital, Something and something of the China.\nEmbassy of India, Internati'
```

Comment: seems this solution has errors in Python 2.7 where it comes up: "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"

Comment: @redrubia Fixed. However I believe the message of the error is bogus. The regex always had 1 *named* group, but many non-named groups.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
def removeCountry(name):
    for country in countries:
          name =  re.sub('(?<!of (the )?)' + country + '$', '', name).strip()
```

Using negative lookbehind re.sub just matches and replaces when country is not preceded by of or of the

Comment: great idea but doesn't work: 'look-behind requires fixed-width pattern'