# operating with string, list & dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a list & a dictionary.

```
l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
d = {'aw.one' : '#aw.one', 'aw.two' : '#aw.two'}
```

Now, I have a string :

```
s = "this is one sentence"
```

I want to check if any items in list l is present in string or not. If yes, then I want to get the value from dictionary whose key contains that item from list.

for example, in given example
- 'one' from string is present in list l
- then I need #aw.one to be printed.

If my string is :

```
s = "this is two balls"
```

it should print

```
#aw.two.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718345/python-how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-words-exist-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward way is to iterate the list and check if the word is in `s` and then iterate the dictionary keys to check if any of them has the word in it, like this

```
for item in l:
    if item in s:
        for key in d:
            if item in key:
                print d[key]
```

Instead of writing the same in multiple lines, we can even write that like this

```
print ", ".join(", ".join(d[k] for k in d if i in k) for i in l if i in s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best approach is build a dict which keys are value parts, so to find if it exists only cost O(1)

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> d = {'aw.one' : '#aw.one', 'aw.two' : '#aw.two'}
>>> s = "this is two balls"
>>> d_reversed = {
...     v_part:k
...     for k,v in d.iteritems()
...     for v_part in re.findall(r"[\w']+", v) #for all words from every value
...     
... }
>>> for w in s.split():
...     if w in d_reversed:
...         print d_reversed[w], d[d_reversed[w]] #print the key from the main dict, and its value
...         break
... 
aw.two #aw.two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing with couple list comprehensions and a filter lambda:

```
matching_words = [ word for word in l if word in s ]
matching_values = [ value for key, value in d.items() if list(filter(lambda x: x in key, matching_words)) ]
for value in matching_values:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your key prefix is always the same:

```
>>> l = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> d = {'aw.one' : '#aw.one', 'aw.two' : '#aw.two'}
>>> s = "this is one sentence"
>>> print(''.join(d.get('aw.{}'.format(w)) for w in l if w in s))
#aw.one
```

Answer (score 0):

Using set and dictionary:

```
print [d['aw.'+i] for i in (set(s.split()) & set(l)) if 'aw.'+i in d]
```