# Check if string contains more than one element from array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, list

I'm using regular expression in my project, and have an array like this :

```
myArray = [
    r"right",
    r"left",
    r"front",
    r"back"
]
```

Now I want to check if the string, for example

```
message = "right left front back"
```

has more than one match in this array, my purpose here is to have an if being true only if there is only one word matching one of the array.

I tried a lot of things, like this one

```
if any(x in str for x in a):
```

but I never make it work with a limited amount.

Comment: How about `matches = [x for x in a if x in str]`.  You could then check the number of matches with `len(matches)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to determine if a list of words exist in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718345/python-how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-words-exist-in-a-string)

Comment: @Michal Frystacky Didn't came across that one, even if i checked a lot before, stackoverflow is so huge ! thanks !

Comment: @ThaoD5 Its no problem, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matches = [a for a in myArray if a in myStr]
```

Now check the `len()` of `matches`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) here. The trick here is that `True` is calculated as `1` while finding the `sum`. Hence you can utilize the `in` directly.

```
>>> sum(x in message for x in myArray)
4
>>> sum(x in message for x in myArray) == 1
False
```

`if` clause can look like

```
>>> if(sum(x in message for x in myArray) == 1):
...     print("Only one match")
... else:
...     print("Many matches")
... 
Many matches
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed, with the if statement example, perfect ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
any(x in message for x in myArray)
```

Evaluates to `True` if ***at least one*** string in `myArray` is found in `message`.

```
sum(x in message for x in myArray) == 1
```

Evaluates to `True` if ***exactly one*** string in `myArray` is found in `message`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for one of the fastest ways to do it use intersections of sets:

```
mySet  = set(['right', 'left', 'front', 'back'])
message = 'right up down left'

if len(mySet & set(message.split())) > 1:
    print('YES')
```