# Python creating a regex from a list and its variations

Tags: python, list, difflib

I have a list of months in Latin:

```
latinMonths = ['januarii', 'februarii','martii', 'aprilis', 'maii', 'junii', 'julii', 'augusti', 'septembris', 'octobris', 'novembris', 'decembris']
```

which unfortunately in my text I find variations of them spelled differently ex: 'januarij' or 'septembrjs' etc...

I am trying to scan the text to find the exact word as the the list or variations of it.

I know I can use difflib and found that I can check a sentence with a list of words in this post: [Python: how to determine if a list of words exist in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718345/python-how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-words-exist-in-a-string). Is there a way I can combine both, thus finding an instance in a string where the months in the list or variations of it exist?

ex: If I have the text "primo januarij 1487" I would like to return true as januarij is a close match to january while if I have 'I love tomatoes' neither of the words are a close match or exact match to the words in the list

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do. Can you give an example?

Comment: I think you might want to match all the words within a [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 1 from the words in your list. A naive but working way to do so is to split your text in a list of words and compute for each word the distance to all the months.

Comment: I was thinking of that but unfortunately my text can be quite long and contain a date...it can be quite inefficient to check all the words in the text...thought there was another way :S

Comment: It's impossible to generate regex for undefined variations of words. If you want a regex then it's going to be required that you explicitly list all the variations you expect to find.

Comment: thanks maybe I can generate the variations expected! :)

Comment: And if you can list all the variations you expect to find, you could also solve this without regex. ;) Maybe a good starting point would be something like this: Find all the matches of `\bjan[a-z]*\b`, make that list unique, throw out all false positives, repeat with the same process the other months - and there is your list of variations.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be achieved using [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) as follows:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def fuzzy_months(text:str, months:list, treshold:float = 0.9)->bool:
    """Return if a word within the given text is close enough to any given month."""
    return max([fuzz.ratio(month,word) for month in latinMonths for word in test_string.split()])/100>= treshold
```

For example taking in consideration the following phrases `test_string = 'lorem ipsum siptum abet septembrjs'` and `fail_string = 'do you want to eat at McDonald?'`:

```
fuzzy_months(test_string, latinMonths)
>>> True

fuzzy_months(fail_string, latinMonths)
>>> False
```