# Loading a string into numpy record array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a string formatted that looks like

```
contents = "1,2,3;\n4,5,6;"
```

Which I want to load into `numpy` record array with `dtype`

```
structure = {'names': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'formats': ['i4']*3}
```

To create something like

```
array([(1,2,3),
       (4,5,6)],
      dtype = [('foo', '<i4'), ('bar', '<i4'), ('baz', '<i4')])
```

But [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) only supports 1D arrays, and I can't use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) because it is not a file.

The documentation of `numpy.loadtxt` seems to suggest I can use a generator, so I have used the split generator detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3865367/1499032) to create a generator and have done

```
np.loadtxt(itersplit(contents, sep=";"), delimiter=",", dtype=structure)
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StringIO.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO):

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> c = StringIO(contents.replace(';', ''))
>>> np.loadtxt(c, delimiter=",", dtype=structure)
array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('foo', '<i4'), ('bar', '<i4'), ('baz', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Or [`io.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html#io.StringIO) for Python 3

Comment: @fophillips Indeed. ;-)