# Is an intermediate list necessary in a multi-level list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Here is a specific example:

```
my_dict={k:int(encoded_value) 
         for (k,encoded_value) in 
             [encoded_key_value.split('=') for encoded_key_value in 
              many_encoded_key_values.split(',')]}
```

The question is about the internal list [], can it be avoided, e.g.:

```
# This will not parse
my_dict={k:int(encoded_value) 
         for (k,encoded_value) in 
             encoded_key_value.split('=') for encoded_key_value in 
             many_encoded_key_values.split(',')}
```

..., which is invalid syntax:

`NameError: name 'encoded_key_value' is not defined`

Sample data: `aa=1,bb=2,cc=3,dd=4,ee=-5`

Comment: for this particular example maybe even `literal_eval` from `ast` could be helpful with some text manipulations.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I've also tried `result = ast.literal_eval('dict('+many_encoded_key_values+')')`. But I'm curious, it doesn't work: `... raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tried `res = ast.literal_eval('{"' + many_encoded_key_values.replace('=', '":').replace(',', ',"') + '}')` and it did but it looked too ugly to post.

Comment: whoa, some serious case specific parsing hacks, there :)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn The pain in the neck was quoting the `abc`s. But @Roman has a very valid point.. Why doesn't his `literal_eval` work?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could avoid creating an intermediate list by using an intermediate generator expression:

```
my_dict={k:int(encoded_value)
         for (k,encoded_value) in
             (encoded_key_value.split('=') for encoded_key_value in
              many_encoded_key_values.split(','))}
```

syntax-wise this is almost the same; instead of generating an intermediate list first and then using the elements, the elements are consumed on the fly.

---

making this overly verbose you could use a 'data pipeline' that consist of generators:

```
eq_statements = (item.strip() for item in many_encoded_key_values.split(','))
var_i = (var_i.split('=') for var_i in eq_statements)
my_dict = {var: int(i) for var, i in var_i}
print(my_dict)
```

(unfortunately `.split` does not return a generator so considering saving space this is not of much use... for handling large files things like this may come in handy.)

found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770397/4954037) which has `split` as an iterator. just in case...

Comment: Interesting, this avoid temporary storage and iterates the items instead.

Comment: yes, added an overly verbose variant that should illustrate the (lazy) generator evaluation of it...

Comment: thanks, this looks like a good approach for n-level expressions to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 5):

As was mentioned, generator expression will enhance your approach avoiding creating inner list. But there is a shorter way to obtain the needed result, using `re.findall()` function:

```
result = {k:int(v) for k,v in re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^,]+)', many_encoded_key_values)}
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'dd': 4, 'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'ee': -5, 'cc': 3}
```

---

The alternative approach would be using `re.finditer()` function which returns `'callable_iterator'` instance:

```
result = {m.group(1):int(m.group(2)) for m in re.finditer(r'(\w+)=([^,]+)', many_encoded_key_values)}
```

Comment: An interesting approach using a regex to, logically at least, "strength reduce" the expression to one level.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn, yes. It would be even easier if we have ampersand separated items `many_encoded_key_values = 'aa=1,7&bb=2&cc=3&dd=4&ee=-5'`

Comment: `findall()` **does** built a `list` though.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, it does, but it also avoids all split operations (besides, my approach idea is **a shorter way**)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn there is [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.finditer) which is a generator.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn, see my update, alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a functional approach:

```
def convert(s):
    k, v = s.split('=')
    return k, int(v)

d = dict(map(convert, data.split(',')))
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'aa': '1', 'bb': '2', 'cc': '3', 'dd': '4', 'ee': '-5'}
```

Comment: I want integers for the values, though. Please update your answer.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Ah, ok.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn In that case, hiro protagonist's 1st method is probably the best way. However, I've added a functional version which avoids an intermediate list. In Python 2, `map` does build a list, but not in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

a simple and compact variant that is very close to your original attempt:

```
d = {v.strip(): int(i) for s in data.split(',') for v, i in (s.split('='),)}
```

the only additional 'trick' was to wrap `s.split('=')` inside a tuple (surrounding it with parentheses: `(s.split('='),)`) in order to get both elements of `split` in the same `for` iteration. the rest is straightforward.

Comment: ...sorry for the additional answer(s). but i felt like this should be possible in a simpler way that what i presented first. this feels much more natural to me.