# Read elements one-by-one from one line like cin >> in C++

Tags: python, python-3.x

Task:

> You are given a sequence of N integers. Find how many elements of this
>   sequence is equal to the first element of this sequence (do not count
>   the first element).
>
> N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6) 
>   
> Those numbers do not exceed 10^9 by modulo (abs())
>
> Examples:
>   input: 
>   6
>   -5 7 0 -5 3 -5 
>   output: 
>   2
>
> input: 
>   6
>   5 7 0 -5 3 -5 
>   output: 
>   0

There is a memory limit and a time limit: **32MB**, **1 second**.

Everything is great with time. My solution is working perfectly with small tests:

```
input()
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(arr.count(arr[0]) - 1)
```

With tremendous test cases, I get a Memory Limit Exceeded error.
What I need to do is to get one-by-one values from one-line input and then delete them so I will not exceed the memory limit.

**Question**: how to get values one-by-one (not as a list) when one-line input in Python.

**EDIT1**
It's not a proper solution - [Is there a generator version of `string.split()` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862010/is-there-a-generator-version-of-string-split-in-python) . We still read the whole line. If I use that solution I get Time Limit Exceeded error. The previous version of question - [Read elements one-by-one from one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922580/read-elements-one-by-one-from-one-line?noredirect=1#comment104107919_58922580)

Comment: Is this problem part of a contest??

Comment: You're not getting a Memory Limit Exceeded error anymore. Therefore that IS a proper solution. You should focus on limiting the time your solution needs...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read elements one-by-one from one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922580/read-elements-one-by-one-from-one-line)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco First it's my question. Second no.

Comment: YOU wrote that you have a Time Limit Exceeded Error... It's not related to memory...

Comment: @RiccardoBucco because if you exceed the Time Limit compiler automatically shutting down your program immediately. It doesn't mean that no problems with memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, everyone, for the list generator. I modified it for my problem. This solution works perfectly for the problem. I hope it will help someone.

```
import re


def split_iter():
    return (x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(r"[-0-9']+", input()))


input()
gen = split_iter()
first = next(gen)
ans = 0
for i in gen:
    if i == first:
        ans += 1
print(ans)
```

[Test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O3kq.png)