# to change a text file containing multiline strings

Tags: python, editing

I have a text file consisting of multiline (hundreds of lines actually) strings. Each of the strings starts with '&' sign. I want to change my text file in a way that only the first 300 characters of each string remain in the new file. How I can do this by using python?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file and loop over the lines to do what you want. Strings are easily slicable in python to get the first 300 to write to another file.

```py
file = open(path,"r")
lines = file.readlines()
newFile = open(newPath,"w")

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    newLine = line[0:301]
    newFile.writelines([newLine])
```

Hope this is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
# Open output file in append mode
with open('output.txt', 'a') as out_file:
    # Open input file in read mode
    with open("input.txt", "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            # Take first 300 characters from line
            # I believe this works even when line is < 300 characters
            new_line = line[0:300]

            # Write new line to output
            # (You might need to add '\n' for new lines)
            out_file.write(new_line)

            print(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string method `split` to split your lines, then you can use slices to keep only the 300 first characters of each split.

```
with open("oldFile.txt", "rt") as old_file, open("newFile.txt", "wt") as new_file:
    for line in old_file.read().split("&"):
        new_file.write("&{}\n".format(line[:300]))
```

This version preserves ends of line `\n` within your strings.

If you want to remove ends of line in each individual string, you can use `replace`:

```
with open("oldFile.txt", "rt") as old_file, open("newFile.txt", "wt") as new_file:
    for line in old_file.read().split("&"):
        new_file.write("&{}\n".format(line.replace("\n", "")[:300]))
```

Note that your new file will end with an empty line.

Another note is, depending on the size of your file, you may rather use a [generator function version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770397/10409093), instead of `split` which results in the whole file content being loaded in memory as a list of strings.

Comment: Thankyou very mych brain for your answer. It worked for mey EXCEPT that I also want to retain the character "&" in each 300 characters. It should be Included for each entry and not Excluded.

Comment: Thankyou very mych brain for your answer. It worked for me EXCEPT that I also want to retain the character "&" in each 300 characters. It should be Included for each entry and not Excluded.

Comment: Do you mean that these `&` are not line separators or that you want to include them back in the beginning of your lines ?

Comment: I want to include them back in the begining of my lines so that each line consists of 300 characters, including '&' .

Comment: The most straightforward way to do it is to include them back when formatting (and taking one less character to keep a length of 300). I updated my answer.

Comment: You are incredible Brain. It really worked for me., Ohhhhh you programmers. You guys are so incredible. Thank you very much again.