# Python: truncate a file to 100 lines or less

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python - just wondering if there was a library function or easy way to truncate a file to the first 100 lines or less?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
with open("my.file", "r+") as f:
    [f.readline() for x in range(100)]
    f.truncate()
```

**EDIT** A 5 % speed increase can be had by instead using the xrange iterator and not storing the entire list:

```
with open("my.file", "r+") as f:
    for x in xrange(100):
        f.readline()
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the solutions here: [Iterate over the lines of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054604/iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-string) and just grab the first hundred, i.e.

```
import itertools
lines = itertools.islice(iter, 100)
```