# Reduce memory footprint from for loops and lists

Tags: python, profiling

I have a function that I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of. The maximum amount of memory I can use is only 500MB. It seems that using `.split('\t')` and for loops is really using a lot of memory. Is there are way that I can reduce this memory usage?

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
10     35.4 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
11                             def function(username):
12     35.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       key = s3_bucket.get_key(username)
13     85.7 MiB     50.2 MiB       file_data = key.get_contents_as_string()
14    159.3 MiB     73.6 MiB       g = [x for x in file_data.splitlines() if not x.startswith('#')]
15    144.8 MiB    -14.5 MiB       del file_data
16    451.8 MiB    307.1 MiB       data = [x.split('\t') for x in g]
17    384.0 MiB    -67.8 MiB       del g
18
19    384.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = []
20    661.7 MiB    277.7 MiB       for row in data:
21    661.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           d.append({'key': row[0], 'value':row[3]})
22    583.7 MiB    -78.0 MiB       del data
25    700.8 MiB    117.1 MiB       database[username].insert_many(d)
26    700.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       return
```

UPDATE1

As per the suggestion of @Jean-FrançoisFabre and @Torxed, it's an improvement but the generators still seem to take a large amount of memory.

@martineau I'd prefer to use MongoDB `.insert_many()` as iterating over the keys and performing `.insert()` is *much* slower.

```
20     35.3 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
21                             def function(username):
22     85.4 MiB     50.1 MiB       file_data = s3_bucket.get_key(username).get_contents_as_string()
23    610.5 MiB    525.2 MiB       data = (x.split('\t') for x in isplitlines(file_data) if not x.startswith('#'))
24    610.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = ({'key': row[0], 'value':row[3]} for row in data)
25    123.3 MiB   -487.2 MiB       database[username].insert_many(d)
26    123.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return
```

UDPATE2

I've identified the source of the memory usage as this profile shows:

```
21     41.6 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
22                             def insert_genotypes_into_mongodb(username):
23     91.1 MiB     49.4 MiB       file_data = s3_bucket.get_key(username).get_contents_as_string()
24     91.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       genotypes = (x for x in isplitlines(file_data) if not x.startswith('#'))
25     91.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = ({'rsID': row.split('\t')[0], 'genotype':row.split('\t')[3]} for row in genotypes)
26                                 # snps_database[username].insert_many(d)
27     91.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       return
```

The `insert_many()` function clearly resolves the previous lines causing the whole list to be loaded into memory and confuses the profiler.

The solution is insert the keys into MongoDB in chunks:

```
22     41.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
23                             def insert_genotypes_into_mongodb(username):
24     91.7 MiB     50.2 MiB       file_data = s3_bucket.get_key(username).get_contents_as_string()
25    180.2 MiB     88.6 MiB       genotypes = (x for x in isplitlines(file_data) if not x.startswith('#'))
26    180.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = ({'rsID': row.split('\t')[0], 'genotype':row.split('\t')[3]} for row in genotypes)
27     91.7 MiB    -88.6 MiB       chunk_step = 100000
28
29     91.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       has_keys = True
30    127.4 MiB     35.7 MiB       keys = list(itertools.islice(d,chunk_step))
31    152.5 MiB     25.1 MiB       while has_keys:
32    153.3 MiB      0.9 MiB           snps_database[username].insert_many(keys)
33    152.5 MiB     -0.9 MiB           keys = list(itertools.islice(d,chunk_step))
34    152.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           if len(keys) == 0:
35    104.9 MiB    -47.6 MiB               has_keys = False
36                                 # snps_database[username].insert_many(d[i*chunk_step:(i+1)*chunk_step])
37    104.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       return
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Iterate over generators and generator expressions (or other lazily evaluated constructs) in lieu of lists.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but have you tried forcing garbage collection by `import gc` and then `gc.collect()` statement after `del g` and `del data`.

Comment: `data = [x.split('\t') for x in g]` That's because you're not using the list as a iterator, you're using is basically as `x = list(something)` which has to wait for ALL data to be collected before creating the `data` variable. use a `for obj in x.split()` instead.

Comment: Could you incrementally insert the contents of `d` instead of putting all those dictionaries in the list with one call to `database[username].insert_many(d)`? If so, then you can use some of the other suggestions for incrementally processing the rest of data instead of reading and maintaining it all in memory at once. Another approach would be to write it out to a temporary file and read it back in a row/line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `splitlines()` as it creates a `list`, you need an iterator. So you could use [Iterate over the lines of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054604/iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-string) example to get an iterator version of `splitlines()`:

```
def isplitlines(foo):
    retval = ''
    for char in foo:
        retval += char if not char == '\n' else ''
        if char == '\n':
            yield retval
            retval = ''
    if retval:
        yield retval
```

Personal note: this isn't very efficient because of string concatenation. I've rewritten that using a list and `str.join`. My version:

```
def isplitlines(buffer):
    retval = []
    for char in buffer:
        if not char == '\n':
            retval.append(char)
        else:
            yield "".join(retval)
            retval = []
    if retval:
        yield "".join(retval)
```

then, avoid using `del` as no intermediate list (except the one splitting the rows) are used. Just "compress" your code, skipping the `g` part and create `d` as a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension:

```
def function(username):
   key = s3_bucket.get_key(username)
   file_data = key.get_contents_as_string()
   data = (x.split('\t') for x in isplitlines(file_data) if not x.startswith('#'))
   d = ({'key': row[0], 'value':row[3]} for row in data)
   database[username].insert_many(d)
```

this may be "onelined" a little more, but would be difficult to understand. And the current code is OK. See that as chained generator comprehension/expressions working together with only one big source chunk of memory: `file_data`

Comment: Thanks! See my updated post there's an improvement but still has a very large footprint.

Comment: BTW can someone explain that line `24    610.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = ({'key': row[0], 'value':row[3]} for row in data)`. What are the values? before/after? and why does the generator declaration (not running) allocates that much memory? that may be the key of all this.

Comment: Yes - these are the return values from memory profiler: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler

Answer (score 0):

The solution is insert the keys into MongoDB in chunks:

```
22     41.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
23                             def insert_genotypes_into_mongodb(username):
24     91.7 MiB     50.2 MiB       file_data = s3_bucket.get_key(username).get_contents_as_string()
25    180.2 MiB     88.6 MiB       genotypes = (x for x in isplitlines(file_data) if not x.startswith('#'))
26    180.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       d = ({'rsID': row.split('\t')[0], 'genotype':row.split('\t')[3]} for row in genotypes)
27     91.7 MiB    -88.6 MiB       chunk_step = 100000
28
29     91.7 MiB      0.0 MiB       has_keys = True
30    127.4 MiB     35.7 MiB       keys = list(itertools.islice(d,chunk_step))
31    152.5 MiB     25.1 MiB       while has_keys:
32    153.3 MiB      0.9 MiB           snps_database[username].insert_many(keys)
33    152.5 MiB     -0.9 MiB           keys = list(itertools.islice(d,chunk_step))
34    152.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           if len(keys) == 0:
35    104.9 MiB    -47.6 MiB               has_keys = False
36                                 # snps_database[username].insert_many(d[i*chunk_step:(i+1)*chunk_step])
37    104.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       return
```