# Python iterate file content returned by urlopen

Tags: python, loops, iteration, urlopen

i have a python script that simply get file content from a specific URL and show the content using print command.

This is what actually i done:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib

url = "http://www.mywebsite/file.txt"

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
    resp = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(resp)
```

When i print `resp` i see correctly the content of the file. Now, i would like to iterate line by line the content or resp in order to perform some string check for each row iterated.

Can you help me please?
thank in advance

Comment: See the duplicat, which addresses Python 2, but applies to `urllib.request` just as much. Read your data in chunks.

Comment: Or see [Iterate over the lines of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054604/iterate-over-the-lines-of-a-string) if you're not concerned about reading the file in slowly but just want to split the string into lines.

Comment: @glibdud: why do that? You can just loop over the response object, iteration yields lines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It wasn't clear the asker knew how to do either... consider it a chance to learn two things with one question.