# Inserting newline characters every 64-ish characters

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

Can someone point me in the right direction on this..

I have a string that contains sentences of words
e.g. 'He was trying to learn a pythonic, or regex, way of solving his problem'

The string in question is quite large and I need to break it up into multiple lines, where each line can not exceed 64 characters.
BUT I cant just insert a line break every 64 characters. I need to ensure the break occurs at the closest character (from a set of characters) before the 64th character, to ensure the line does not exceed 64 characters. 
e.g. I can only insert a line break after a space, comma or full stop

I also need the solution to be quite efficient as it is an action that will occur many, many times.

## Using textwrap

I'm not sure textwrap is the way to go for my problem because I need to preserve the original line breaks in the input string.
Example:

```
long_str = """
123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
Line 1: Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called machine intelligence, 
Line 2: is intelligence demonstrated by machines, 
Line 3: in contrast to the natural intelligence displayed by humans and  other animals. 
Line 4: In computer science AI research is defined as
"""
lines = textwrap.wrap(long_str, 60, break_long_words=False)
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

What I want is this:

> ```
> 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
> Line 1: Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called 
> machine intelligence, 
> Line 2: is intelligence demonstrated by machines, 
> Line 3: in contrast to the natural intelligence displayed 
> by humans and other animals. 
> Line 4: In computer science AI research is defined as
> ```

But textwrap gives me this:

> ```
>  123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
> Line 1: Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called
> machine intelligence,  Line 2: is intelligence demonstrated
> by machines,  Line 3: in contrast to the natural
> intelligence displayed by humans and other animals.  Line 4:
> In computer science AI research is defined as
> ```

I suspect that Regex is probably the answer but I'm out of my depth trying to solve this with regex.

Comment: It's in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/textwrap.html

Comment: I looked at this and it is almost what I am after but it doesnt seem preserve existing line breaks.
I ONLY need to wrap lines/sentences where the line exceeds 64 characters and i need to preserve the format of the rest of the string

Comment: For an easy solution, split it into lines and call textwrap on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the long string into separate lines on the newline. Wrap each separate line "as usual", then concatenate everything again to a single string.

```
import textwrap

long_str = """
123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
Line 1: Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called machine intelligence, 
Line 2: is intelligence demonstrated by machines, 
Line 3: in contrast to the natural intelligence displayed by humans and  other animals. 
Line 4: In computer science AI research is defined as
"""

lines = []
for line in long_str.split('\n'):
    lines += textwrap.wrap(line, 60, break_long_words=False)
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

As `textwrap` returns a list of strings, you don't need to do anything else than keep on pasting them together, and join them at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I had considered doing that but I was convinced there had to be a better way.
If I add drop_whitespace=False then it gives me what I need

Comment: Im going to accept this as the answer because to me, a Python novice, the readability of this solution is preferable when compared to the solution proposed by @DonQuiKong

Comment: @CHaste do that, this answer does explain a little more too. Just as a side note, list comprehensions are “more pythonic“ and faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
import textwrap

def f1(foo): 
    return iter(foo.splitlines())

long_str = """
123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789
Line 1: Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called machine intelligence, 
Line 2: is intelligence demonstrated by machines, 
Line 3: in contrast to the natural intelligence displayed by humans and  other animals. 
Line 4: In computer science AI research is defined as
"""
[print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(l, 64, break_long_words=False))) for l in f1(long_str)]
```

*with the iterating over the lines of a string per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3054604/7322095)*

Comment: How does this compare to the suggestion from usr2564301?

Comment: @CHaste it's pretty much the same (list comprehension instead of for). However, mine was posted a few seconds earlier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It might help us answer your question if you could provide any code you have already attempted. That being said, I believe the following example code will preserve existing line breaks, wrap lines exceeding 64 characters and preserve the format of the rest of the string.

```
import textwrap

long_str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " \
       "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " \
       "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris" \
       "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in" \
       "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. " \
       "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui" \
       "officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

lines = textwrap.wrap(long_str, 64, break_long_words=False)

print('\n'.join(lines))
```

The output from Python is:

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
> enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
> laborisnisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
> dolor inreprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
> fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
> proident, sunt in culpa quiofficia deserunt mollit anim id est
> laborum.
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Andy. But I'm not sure textwrap will solve this. I have updated my OP based on your input

Comment: That's not preserving the original line breaks.